Nested ISBLANK, Else formula statement
Bare with me because my knowledge is limited. I'm looking to create something that would filter through 4 cells, determining if they are blank and if not, would enter the value in that cell into a formula with a value from another cell.
So, if C20 is blank, move to next cell, otherwise C20/C26, if C21 is blank, move to next cell, otherwise c21/C26, if C22 is blank, move to next cell, otherwise C22/C26, if C23 is blank, move to next cell, otherwise C23/C26, otherwise blank
Sort of deal.. hope that makes sense.
Thanks in advance!
I tried to enter =IF(ISBLANK(C20)," ",(C20/C26) which works! YAY! but when I try to nest multiple checks together they dont work.
